# How to write empty associative array ({}) to MongoDB from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, associative-array

When I try to insert empty **associative** array (`hashmap`/`dictionary`/`dict`/`{}`) to MongoDB from PHP, it is always inserted as non-associative empty array (`list`/`[]`). Can I force associative array?

Example:

```
$m = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = $db->selectCollection('test');

// 1: inserts []
$d = array( 'x' => array() );
$collection->insert($d);

// 2: inserts []
$d = array( 'y' => array('a'=>'123') );
unset($d['y']['a']);
$collection->insert($d);

// 3: inserts {}
$d = array( 'z' => array('a'=>'123') );
$collection->insert($d);
$collection->update(array('_id' => $d['_id']), array('$unset' => array('z.a'=>true)));
```

And the results:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510fb9ede695c5381a000000"), "x" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510fb9ede695c5381a000001"), "y" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510fb9ede695c5381a000002"), "z" : { } }
```

The third way does what I want, but it is a bit awkward and requires two queries. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether you store an empty object or array, what's the difference? In BSON, [arrays and objects are stored the same way, as a dict](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification). Anyways, to your question.

For the PHP MongoDB driver an empty array is just that, an empty array, so it stores it as an array. When you add a key/value pair to the array, that's how the driver understands it should store an object.

If you really want to store an empty object, try :

```
$d = new \stdClass();
$collection->insert(array('z' => $d));
```

Comment: Huge thanks, works perfectly! I knew there had to be a simple way. :) Btw, I guess the question in first line was rhetorical? ;)

Comment: I'm glad i could help! But, no the question wasn't rhetorical. I can understand if you want to use empty arrays by default. That way you can $push/$addToSet/$pull/etc later. But why do you need it to be an object by defualt? You need to use $set anyway, which would change the array to an object if the value is an object. It may be something to do with your driver/ORM?

Comment: The major reason is that dicts (`{}`) are a natural choice for my type of data... I have unique keys that have some values. With lists (`[]`) I would have to enforce keys' uniqueness by hand. In this case PHP just prepares the structure (that is: inserts the document), the data is updated later from Python backend. Hope it makes sense... :)

Comment: "dicts ({}) are a natural choice for my type of data". That's my kind of design decision! Thumbs up for defining intended use of schema in the document.

Answer (score 4):

There is in fact a difference in that it will be treated as non-associative [] if empty and will then not allow setting of an associative key, throwing an exception:

```
MongoCursorException: can't append to array using string field name
```

You should cast as an object as such:

```
$d = array( 'x' => (object) array() );
$collection->insert($d);
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-172